# Apply style on form defined in master page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, master-pages

How do I apply a css style on a container (`<form>`) element that is defined in the master page of my current page?

## Details

I need to define `<form>` element in the master page because the master page contains a few server and client side controls for the navigation bar. Now in my child page (or whatever it is called) I need to apply a style to the `<form>` element that is specific to this child page only. Is it possible through some css selector or something? Note that I can't define a `<form>` element in the child page because nested forms are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client's perspective, there's no difference between master and regular pages. They're all merged into a single document.

So this should work just fine.

On the master page...

```
<form runat="server">
```

On the client page...

```
<style>
form {background-color: white}
</style>
```

Comment: hmmm... should have thought of that. Perhaps because the CSS file I have applies styles through classes (unlike your approach of applying them through element name), so I couldn't think how I could apply a CSS class on an element of the master page. Thanks, it was helpful.

Comment: You could give the form an ID and assign it like that, if you plan on having other forms on your site. The same principle applies, master page and a regular page become a single HTML document given to the client.